# In my Crawl Stats, 23% of requests are "Unauthorized" - is that bad?

Tags: seo, google-analytics, googlebot, web-crawlers, crawl-errors

Am I correct in thinking that having 23% of all crawl requests being blocked by "Unauthorized" 401/407 is NOT good?

68% of my crawl requests return 200 (OK) which is good of course.

Is this an urgent thing to fix? I'm thinking that perhaps those directories ought to be blocked by robots.txt?

Comment: Why would it be "bad"? Presumably you are intentionally blocking this content? Why are you blocking it? `robots.txt` simply prevents (good) bots from crawling content, not users - which is not the same thing. (But blocking with `robots.txt` vs 401 is not going to make any difference SEO-wise.)

Comment: Why is this tagged "google-anyltics"?  Most bots don't run JavaScript and their hits are never measured by GA.    You also wouldn't normally include the GA tracking snippet on 401/407 Unauthorized pages.   Are you actually trying to use GA to measure this?